# How to ignore Sonar rule to specific line of code in C#?

Tags: c#, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I use SonarLint. I want the sonar test not to be performed for a specific line. I used `// NOSONAR` but it didn't work. Does not specify the error number.

[image: SS]

The error still appears in SonarLint when I use `//NOSONAR`. But in the main project (SonarQube) the error no longer appears.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is Visual Studio suggestion, not SonarLint warning. Also, I believe NOSONAR is not supported in Visual Studio. You can either suppress in source:

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0017
<your code>
#pragma warning restore IDE0017
```

Or in suppression file:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Style", "IDE0017:Simplify object initialization", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "member", Target = "~M:<your class and your method>")]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [SuppressMessageAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute) with methods or classes. It allows suppressing a warning in only certain parts of your project or file. For example, **you can suppress a warning in a method or class scope**:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage(
    "Style",
    "IDE0017:Simplify object initialization",
    Justification = "<Pending>")]
void SetName(string name)
{
    var person = new Person();
    person.Name = name;
}
```

or

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage(
    "Style",
    "IDE0017:Simplify object initialization",
    Justification = "<Pending>")]
class MyClass
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To suppress warning you have two options.

1. #pragma warning disable.
   if you are not sure what pragma you should use, install SonarLint extension
   for your visual studio.
2. //NOSONAR
   It does work, if it is running through SonarQube server extension.
   Example if you're code is running through SonarQube task under build
   pipeline.